# How to create a frontend form using Ultimate Module Creator

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using an Ultimate Module Creator for one of the custom form on website where the form value is submitted from frontend and is stored and displayed in Magento backend.

I created a module using Module creator and was able to successfully create a backend form but didn't found an option to create the same form on frontend. Instead there is an option to display List and Detail page for the entered entries.

Can anyone please guide me how to create the form on frontend of the website using Module creator.

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic since it is about a third party Magento Extension.

Comment: See Marius answer for more details. In it's simple form you cannot create a module without an entity associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to create the frontend form for an entity using the Ultimate module creator. It just allows you to kickstart your extension.
It generates the files needed for managing entities in the backend and listing and viewing them in the backend and frontend.
But what you need is already there. You just have to create the form on frontend and use the same logic from the save controller in the backend.